3” PVC for toilet too high in joist cavity causing elbow to be above finished floor
Im moving the toilet across the room.  This caused an issue that after achieving proper fall (which I don’t even have. I only have 1/4” per 18”) the elbow below the toilet flange is too high.
The elbow in the photo actually needs lifted another 1/4” - 1/2” for fall.  It’s just laying there in the photo.  The top of the elbow is 2-1/4” - 2-1/2” above the floor joist and the finished floor will be 1-1/4” above the floor joist putting the top of the elbow above the finished floor by an inch at least.
I intend on cutting the top of the elbow off and the bottom of the toilet flange off and gluing the per usual… Is this kosher.  It will just be a smaller glue joint.
HELP!!!
THANK YOU

There is no photo.

You've got three main options:

Don't move the toilet, leave it where it was across the room since you have the proper drain slope there.
Raise the floor to compensate for the additional height of the proper downward slope. Usually this means raising the entire floor, but sometimes you can work in an elevation change.
Work backwards from the elevation you want, and re-slope the rest of the drain into the downstairs ceiling. Looks like it is finished? So that may be quite a bit of work.

I can't recommend cutting the flange or the elbow and trying to compensate with glue, you're asking for leaks and this is (IMO) the worst place to have a leak.

In my house, a section of floor was raised for that reason, and it works well and looks fine. As mentioned above, avoid DIY splicing - it could cause a s***load of trouble.
